# el nombre ya esta en uso? a que se refiere?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

como soluciono esto?, en la parte de inicio de sesion al intentar restablecer la contraseña, al meter la direccion de correo electrónico pasa este error "cannot use Illuminate/Notifications/Messages/MailMessage as MailMessage because the name is already in use".
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te sugiero agregar tu codigo de como haces el reset de la contraseña

Comment: El mensaje es claro, la línea 8 se repite en la línea 10. Por eso te arroja ese error. Por otra parte, es preferible siempre que subas código y no imagen. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas, tienes dos veces la línea `use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;`, más exactamente en la línea 8 y 10.

El error se refiere a que MailMessage fue «importado o definido» en la línea 8, y en la línea 10 ya no es posible utilizar dicho nombre de clase, porque no sabría a cual de las dos referirse.

En este caso el error es muy sencillo, tan solo suprime una de estas dos líneas (la 8 o la 10).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes importada 2 veces la clase `MailMessage`, puedes utilizar dos clases que se llamen igual dándole un alias a alguna de las dos:

Primera:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
```

Segunda:

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\OtrosMensajes\MailMessage as OtroMensaje;
```

En el segundo caso, la instanciarías con el alias que le diste:

```
$otro_mensaje = new OtroMensaje;
```

Pero en tu caso, dado que la ruta es la misma, deberías de borrar alguna de las que estás usando en la línea 8 y 10.